# Employee Compensations Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a pretty straightforward query that I am essentially hard-coding. I have a table with 3 keys and a description field.

The first key has to do with the type of compensation for an employee (`Award`, `Hourly`, `NonHourly`, `Staff`, `Other`, and `Commission`).

The next key has to do with Payment Frequency. `O` refers to One-Time Payment, `M` to Multiple Payments.

The third key has to do with the Compensation Rate Code. It's like another frequency. `P` means Per Project/Assignment, `H` means Hourly, and `M` means Monthly.

Certain Employee Compensations types are restricted to different types of compensation. In the below query, I've hard-coded every possibility. Is there a better way to write this query than just hard-coding every combination and unioning them together?

```
SELECT 'Award' 
 , 'O' 
 , 'P' 
 , 'Per Project or Assignment' 
  FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Hourly' 
 , 'M' 
 , 'H' 
 , 'Per Hour' 
  FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Hourly' 
 , 'M' 
 , 'P' 
 , 'Per Project or Assignment' 
  FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Hourly' 
 , 'M' 
 , 'M' 
 , 'Per Month' 
  FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Hourly' 
 , 'O' 
 , 'H' 
 , 'Per Hour' 
  FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Hourly' 
 , 'O' 
 , 'P' 
 , 'Per Project/Assignment or Month' 
  FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'NonHourly' 
 , 'M' 
 , 'P' 
 , 'Per Project or Assignment' 
  FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'NonHourly' 
 , 'M' 
 , 'M' 
 , 'Per Month' 
  FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'NonHourly' 
 , 'O' 
 , 'P' 
 , 'Per Project/Assignment or Month' 
  FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Staff' 
 , 'M' 
 , 'H' 
 , 'Per Hour' 
  FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Staff' 
 , 'O' 
 , 'H' 
 , 'Per Hour' 
  FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Other' 
 , 'M' 
 , 'H' 
 , 'Per Hour' 
  FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Other' 
 , 'M' 
 , 'P' 
 , 'Per Project or Assignment' 
  FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Other' 
 , 'M' 
 , 'M' 
 , 'Per Month' 
  FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Other' 
 , 'O' 
 , 'H' 
 , 'Per Hour' 
  FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Other' 
 , 'O' 
 , 'P' 
 , 'Per Project or Assignment' 
  FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Other' 
 , 'O' 
 , 'M' 
 , 'Per Month' 
  FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Commission' 
 , 'O' 
 , 'P' 
 , 'Commission/Tips' 
  FROM DUAL
```

Note that `DUAL` is just a dummy table. I'm not actually selecting anything from any tables.

**EDIT:**

This is the SQL behind a View. I wouldn't be opposed to creating new views to "extract" out pieces of the query if that could be used to simplify it. It creates a view that has the following rows in it:
[image: SQL View results]

Essentially, my query takes the results of 18 SQL statements and unions them together to get 18 rows in the newly created view. Surely, there's a better way to do it?

The second and third keys are represented in a table that maps their character values to a description (e.g. O -> One-Time Payment). The first key is only used for this view.

Comment: Do these values exist in a table? For example could you get each key values with a `SELECT DISTINCT key FROM table` query?

Comment: @TasosK. Not really. The first key is used in this context only. The latter two keys _do_ exist in two separate tables that map their values from a character to a description.

Comment: I have prepared a demo, but I assumed that all data are in the database.   Since this is not the case, you could always keep the query results to a table and simply `SELECT *` that table.

Comment: @TasosK. I added an edit to my post to clarify this. The SQL is the SQL behind a View. It results in 18 rows. I'll edit a picture of the expected rows into the post.

Comment: As Tasos said, why don't you just add this as a table (f.e. named `AwardDescription`) to your database?

Comment: I guess I hadn't thought of that. I guess it would be better. If one of you wants to make an answer saying as much, I'll accept it.

Comment: Queries like that the culprit is often the data design.

Answer (score 2):

This really should be put into a table, if possible.

If such a table already exists, you can take the `SELECT` for your existing view and simply wrap an `INSERT INTO TargetTable` statement around it.

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable
SELECT key1,key2,key3,key4 FROM YourView;
COMMIT;
```

Otherwise, you can `CREATE TABLE TargetTable AS` to generate a new table from your return query.

```
CREATE TABLE TargetTable AS
SELECT key1,key2,key3,key4 FROM YourView;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to turn the statement into a view, as in:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW COMPENSATION_TERMS_VIEW AS
  SELECT 'Award' AS COMPENSATION_TYPE
       , 'O' AS PAYMENT_FREQUENCY
       , 'P' AS COMPENSATION_RATE_CODE
       , 'Per Project or Assignment' AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
  SELECT 'Hourly' AS COMPENSATION_TYPE
       , 'M' AS PAYMENT_FREQUENCY
       , 'H' AS COMPENSATION_RATE_CODE
       , 'Per Hour' AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Hourly' AS COMPENSATION_TYPE
       , 'M' AS PAYMENT_FREQUENCY
       , 'P' AS COMPENSATION_RATE_CODE
       , 'Per Project or Assignment' AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Hourly' AS COMPENSATION_TYPE
       , 'M' AS PAYMENT_FREQUENCY
       , 'M' AS COMPENSATION_RATE_CODE
       , 'Per Month' AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Hourly' AS COMPENSATION_TYPE
       , 'O' AS PAYMENT_FREQUENCY
       , 'H' AS COMPENSATION_RATE_CODE
       , 'Per Hour' AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Hourly' AS COMPENSATION_TYPE
       , 'O' AS PAYMENT_FREQUENCY
       , 'P' AS COMPENSATION_RATE_CODE
       , 'Per Project/Assignment or Month' AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'NonHourly' AS COMPENSATION_TYPE
       , 'M' AS PAYMENT_FREQUENCY
       , 'P' AS COMPENSATION_RATE_CODE
       , 'Per Project or Assignment' AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'NonHourly' AS COMPENSATION_TYPE
       , 'M' AS PAYMENT_FREQUENCY
       , 'M' AS COMPENSATION_RATE_CODE
       , 'Per Month' AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'NonHourly' AS COMPENSATION_TYPE
       , 'O' AS PAYMENT_FREQUENCY
       , 'P' AS COMPENSATION_RATE_CODE
       , 'Per Project/Assignment or Month' AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Staff' AS COMPENSATION_TYPE
       , 'M' AS PAYMENT_FREQUENCY
       , 'H' AS COMPENSATION_RATE_CODE
       , 'Per Hour' AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Staff' AS COMPENSATION_TYPE
       , 'O' AS PAYMENT_FREQUENCY
       , 'H' AS COMPENSATION_RATE_CODE
       , 'Per Hour' AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Other' AS COMPENSATION_TYPE
       , 'M' AS PAYMENT_FREQUENCY
       , 'H' AS COMPENSATION_RATE_CODE
       , 'Per Hour' AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Other' AS COMPENSATION_TYPE
       , 'M' AS PAYMENT_FREQUENCY
       , 'P' AS COMPENSATION_RATE_CODE
       , 'Per Project or Assignment' AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Other' AS COMPENSATION_TYPE
       , 'M' AS PAYMENT_FREQUENCY
       , 'M' AS COMPENSATION_RATE_CODE
       , 'Per Month' AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Other' AS COMPENSATION_TYPE
       , 'O' AS PAYMENT_FREQUENCY
       , 'H' AS COMPENSATION_RATE_CODE
       , 'Per Hour' AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Other' AS COMPENSATION_TYPE
       , 'O' AS PAYMENT_FREQUENCY
       , 'P' AS COMPENSATION_RATE_CODE
       , 'Per Project or Assignment' AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Other' AS COMPENSATION_TYPE
       , 'O' AS PAYMENT_FREQUENCY
       , 'M' AS COMPENSATION_RATE_CODE
       , 'Per Month' AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM DUAL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Commission' AS COMPENSATION_TYPE
       , 'O' AS PAYMENT_FREQUENCY
       , 'P' AS COMPENSATION_RATE_CODE
       , 'Commission/Tips' AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM DUAL
```

Best of luck.